# IE7, 8 and 9 won't show border corners

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border

check out http://jugheads.co/home.html
The slider looks great in chrome, safari and firefox, but in IE7, 8 and 9 the border is all messed up, and the margins are off by small pixel amounts.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I've been looking all over the internet for hours, and I've been trying to debug for hours. -got nothin'

Thanks guys,

Rob

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what you describe, however your page is running in quirks mode, so display can mess up.
Remove the XML header, maybe it will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is in Quirks mode, which causes exactly the problems you're describing.

Quirks mode is usually triggered by either (a) missing the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration, or (b) having invalid HTML code.

The former can be fixed by obviously adding the doctype, and the latter can be dealt with by running you code through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

I note that you already have a doctype, but you have an XML delcaration and a comment before it in the code. I suspect that IE might not like having a comment there, and a bit of Googling revealed links like [this one](http://css-class.com/test/css/selectors/ie7hacktargetingopera4.htm) and [this one](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-bugzilla/2011Feb/0580.html) which suggest my hunch may be right. Try moving your comment down a bit, so it's below the doctype. (The latter of those two links is a proposal by Mozilla to the HTML5 spec committee to formally make comments before the doctype illegal, for various reasons, including the quirks mode issue)

You may also need to move the XML declaration below the doctype; I'm not sure about this (it's been a long time since I bothered with xhtml), but it'd be worth experimenting to see what works.

Hope that helps.